# How can I explain the A a = new B();?

Tags: java

Let's say we have some class structure:

```
     public interface IA { public void doA(); }
     public class A implements IA { public void doA(){ System.out.println("A class doA");}
     public class B extends A { public void doA(){ System.out.println("B class doA"); }
```

And now in a main I state this:

```
     //in a main
     IA ia = new B();
     ia.doA();
```

Am I correct in stating that the the runtime object of `ia` is a B class and it has inherited all the super classes methods and attributes?

The printout from within the imaginary main is `B class doA` as the method `doA` in B will hide the same methods in its super classes?

Comment: [What's the difference between override and new?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-s-the-difference-between-code-override-code-and-code-new-code.aspx?Redirected=true) Whoops. Wrong language. [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between overloading a method and overriding it in Java?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/164353/whats-the-difference-between-overloading-a-method-and-overriding-it-in-java)

Comment: As for your last question: have you tried running the code? This is _very easy_ to test...

Comment: The way I prefer to think of inheritance hierarchies including interfaces is by understanding that "subclass" and "subtype" are different qualities. B is a subclass of A, but a subtype of A and IA. Subtyping relationships are important for defining what variable type you can assign some entity to, and subclass relationships are important for defining what behaviour some entity has.

Comment: C# or Java, still same basic idea ;). @AndresF. I have compiled the code and it does what i expected it to do, Biggest issue for me is how to define why so i can learn it. I think i have got a clearer view of this type of override & overload. Found another link that is not that bad ;) [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) Thnx everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

1. `ia` is of class `B`
2. `ia` is also of class `A` since `B` inherits `A`.
3. `B` **overrrides** `A`'s `doA()` method.